# Selection of range in both column and row direction in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I want to select the data from E1 to untill the cell that contains data in Column H.
is it possible through VBA?.

I have tried with this code:

```
Range(Range("e1").End(xlDown), Range("h1").End(xlDown)).Select
```

But it selects E2 to H2.

Comment: It is not error. It selects only from E2 to H2 @ A.S.H

Comment: that's the normal outcome if your cells `E1` and `H1` are empty while  `E2` and `H2` are not. Is that the case?

Comment: my Cells E1 is with content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
Range("E1:H" & Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
```

This will select the range from E1 to last populated cell of column H

Answer (score 0):

> I want to select the data from E1 to untill the cell that contains data in Column H

Will this work for you?

```
Range("e1", Columns("h").Find("*")).Select
```

Corresponds exactly to what you said if `H1` is always empty.

Unless you meant *the **last** cell that contains data in Column H*? In that case:

```
    Range("e1", Range("h999999").End(xlUp)).Select
```